# multiple else if blocks or continue?

Tags: java, if-statement, continue

While solving a mindless task, a question came to my mind:

```
/**
* Find element by key in binary tree.
*/
public E find(K key) {
    BinaryTreeNode<K, E> node = this.root;
    while (node != null) {
        if (node.getKey().compareTo(key) > 0) { //element in tree too big
            node = node.getLeft();
        } else if (node.getKey().compareTo(key) < 0) { //element in tree too small
            node = node.getRight();
        } else { //found element
            return node.getElement();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

In the `while` block, only one `if` statement can be true. So the `while` block could be written using `continue` instead of `else if`:

```
while (node != null) {
    if (node.getKey().compareTo(key) > 0) { //element in tree too big
        node = node.getLeft();
        continue;
    }
    if (node.getKey().compareTo(key) < 0) { //element in tree too small
        node = node.getRight();
        continue;
    }
    //found element
    return node.getElement();
}
```

Is there any difference in performance between the two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference. The compiler should generate exactly the same bytecode in this case. Hence no performance difference could exist.

Comment: That makes things easy. Thanks for the fast response!

Answer (score 3):

If you are covering all cases you can omit last condition and write simply:

```
else { //found element
    return node.getElement();
}
```

And in your second example you can change:

```
if (node.getKey().compareTo(key) == 0) { //found element
    return node.getElement();
}
```

to simply:

```
return node.getElement();
```

Your two examples are equivalent but first one is easier to read. It is easier to spot that every case is covered when you have:

```
if ..
else if ..
else ..
```

then when we have only `if` blocks.

Comment: Right, the last if is unnecessary.. Thanks for pointing that out!